# Why does a = [10, 20, 30, 40] not [10, 20] in this case？

Tags: python, arrays

```
a = [10, 20]
b = a  
b += [30, 40]  
print(a)
print(b)
```

I understand that b = = [10, 20, 30, 40], but I don't understand why a = [10, 20, 30, 40]?

Comment: `a` and `b` are two names for a single list.  Anything you do to that list is visible via both names.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, a variable is actually a reference to an object.

```py
>>> a = [10, 20]
>>> b = a
>>> id(a)
140351945078976
>>> id(b)
140351945078976
```

In this case, both `a` and `b` were referenced to same array `[10, 20]`. When you append `b`, `a` will have same object and see it.

If you want to have a different object, you should do `b = a[:]` or `b = a.copy()`

Comment: or `b = a + [30, 40]`

Answer (score 0):

`b` and `a` both refer to the *same* list object.

Comment: Is it because b = a ?

Comment: @TechSuperGal2020. Assignment means binding a reference to a name. So whatever `a` referred to, `b` now does too. Once you wrap your mind around that, python will get a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

Because of `b = a`, both `a` and `b` point out same memory.

You can check detailed information and examples here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/

> In python, each variable to which we assign a value/container is
> treated as an object. When we are assigning a value to a variable, we
> are actually binding a name to an object.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is the `concept of references`. All objects in Python have a reference and when you assign one to two names a and b, this results in both `a` and `b` pointing to the **same object**.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when working with Python for a bit. When you say **b = a** in the code above, you are actually creating a **pointer** to **a** in memory. Any changes done on b will affect a because b points to a in memory.

If you aren't familiar with pointers I would check them out for the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if two variables are assigned with the same value, then they point to the same object in the memory, like in this case when b=a then a and b are pointing to the same object in the memory when you make change using b to the object like b+= [30, 40] then the object pointing by a and b both has changed giving you the final output [10,20,30,40]

if you use the code below then your output will be [10,20] for a and [10,20,30,40] for b as the object pointing was changed after printing a

`a = [10, 20],
b = a,
print(a),

b = b + [30, 40] ,
print(b)`